# Is this person in this picture from the squad?

Tags: united-states, congress

The following picture has often been associated with the squad. But who is the lady on the leftmost?

[image]

Comment: "Nancy Pelosi" ... "plus Brandi Carlile, Stevie Nicks, Stacey Abrams".  Hmmm, that doesn't seem to match the picture.

Answer (score 9):

It's slightly blurry, but the image in your question is captioned with the names of the four congresswomen:

> Jahana Hayes
>
> Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez
>
> Nancy Pelosi
>
> Ilhan Omar

Jahana Hayes is Connecticut’s first Black Congresswoman, first elected in 2018 and again in 2020.

She is not typically listed as a member of the Squad.  That informal group originally consisted of Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez of New York, Ilhan Omar of Minnesota, Ayanna Pressley of Massachusetts, and Rashida Tlaib of Michigan. Since 2020, the Squad has grown to include Jamaal Bowman of New York and Cori Bush of Missouri ([The Squad (United States Congress)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Squad_(United_States_Congress)).

Hayes is fairly progressive, and her Republican opponent in 2020, David X. Sullivan said in a campaign ad, "Hayes hangs out with the squad — they’re too radical" ([Jahana Hayes, Connecticut’s 1st Black Congresswoman, Wins 2nd Term](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/04/nyregion/connecticut-house-jahana-hayes.html)), but even he didn't claim that she belonged to that group.

Comment: So what is the significance of "the squad"?

Comment: @Tim nothing really.  It's just four (or maybe six if you count Bowman and Bush), congresswomen with similar politics and who fundraise together.  It's not an official organization.

Comment: @Ryan_L Does "squad" imply four?

Comment: @Tim Not that I'm aware of.  Might be a good question on English.SE

Comment: @Tim.  You are aware that it was a derogatory name given to a group of women in Congress by the Trump admin?

Comment: @BeginnerBiker are you talking about the word "squad"? That wikipedia article says it was used by Ocasio-Cortez. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Squad_(United_States_Congress)

Comment: @BeginnerBiker I don’t doubt that he used it with a snarl, but Representative AOC used it first when she and the other 3 Congresswomen were working together the week or two after they were elected. https://thehill.com/homenews/House/416370-ocasio-cortez-shares-photo-of-her-new-squad-on-capitol-hill

Comment: And Nancy Pelosi is *definitely* not part of the squad.

Comment: @Tim: *squad* does come from *squadra* (square), but it's also used in sports (squadra azzurra) or in the military for ~10 people. (see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squad)

Comment: "four (or maybe six if you count Bowman and Bush), congresswomen": if you count Bowman and Bush, it's five congresswomen and a congressman.

Answer (score 1):

It is Jahana Hayes as it listed in the lower right of the picture

In order from left to right the people are

Jahana Hayes,
Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez,
Nancy Pelosi,
Ilhan Omar

Comment: Is she part of the squad?

Comment: @Tim I don't think she is